# Appending a List at runtime in Python

Tags: python

I'm Creating a project in which i have two lists.
One list is **user_ids** where the user's usernames are stored.
Another is **user_ratings** where the user's ratings are stored.
At the corresponding ***index*** of username, user rating is stored.
If there's a new user, the list is appended dynamically at run-time.
Here's the code:

```
print("Welcome to Movie Predictor")
print("Enter your user id: ")
user_ids=["Vishnu"]
user_ratings=[3.5]
username=input()
print("Signing in...Please Wait!")
if username in user_ids:
    user_index=user_ids.index(username)
    avg_rating=user_ratings[user_index]
    new_user=0
else:
    user_ids.append(username)
    user_ratings.append(3.5)
    avg_rating=3.5
    new_user=1
```

After my first run of the program, I have entered a username which is not there in the list and here are the arrays.

```
user_ids=["Vishnu","Power"]
user_ratings=["3.5","3.5"]
```

But here's the problem. The next time i run it again, My last element *`"Power"`* is getting replaced but a new item is not appended in the list.

Here's the list after 2nd run:

```
user_ids=["Vishnu","Ranger"]
user_ratings=["3.5","3.5"]
```

How to overcome this problem?

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to use two separate lists and call `index`; try to use a dictionary.

Comment: What do you run for a second time? Are you running the script two times? It will not save information in the list between runs.

Comment: Okay i feel dictionary is better idea. But can i append to dict dynamically at runtime? Also just out of curiosity i want to know why two lists are not working. What's the reason or error behind it?

Comment: @A.Albershteyn Second time in the sense, I run it two times back to back in IDE.

Comment: Your script works for me, if I put the second half (starting at  `username=input()`) in a loop.

If you just run the script twice, you will reinitialize your list every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving your data to disk after each run, and reading if back before next run:

```
import os.path

if not os.path.exists("mydatabase.txt"):
    # initialize
    user_ids=["Vishnu"]
    user_ratings=[3.5]
else:
    # read previous data from database file
    user_ids=[]
    user_ratings=[]
    with open("mydatabase.txt", "r") as databasefile:
        for line in databasefile:
             userid, rating_str = line.split()
             rating = float(rating_str)
             user_ids.append(userid)
             user_ratings.append(rating)

print("Welcome to Movie Predictor")
print("Enter your user id: ")
username=input()
print("Signing in...Please Wait!")
if username in user_ids:
    user_index=user_ids.index(username)
    avg_rating=user_ratings[user_index]
    new_user=0
else:
    user_ids.append(username)
    user_ratings.append(3.5)
    avg_rating=3.5
    new_user=1

print("Current user ids: %s" % user_ids)
print("Current user ratings: %s" % user_ratings)

# write data to database file
with open("mydatabase.txt", "w") as databasefile:
    for userid, rating in zip(user_ids, user_ratings):
        databasefile.write("%s %.1f\n" % (userid, rating))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no loop here. You just overwrite the values each time.

try that:

```
A, B = [], []
while True:
    A.append(3.5)
    b = input('B value')
    if b == '':
        break
    B.append(b)
    print(A, B)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear which parts of the code you run again, but it seems that you are resetting your user ID and ratings lists in every run (3d and 4th line). Therefore "Powers" is not being replaced. Rather than that, a new list with Vishnu is created and your new input is added to it after the run.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a loop. The values in the list won't be saved between runs of the script

```
print("Welcome to Movie Predictor")
print("Enter your user id: ")
user_ids=["Vishnu"]
user_ratings=[3.5]

while True:
    username=input()
    print("Signing in...Please Wait!")
    if username in user_ids:
        user_index=user_ids.index(username)
        avg_rating=user_ratings[user_index]
        new_user=0
    else:
        user_ids.append(username)
        user_ratings.append(3.5)
        avg_rating=3.5
        new_user=1
    print("List of users: " + str(user_ids))
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to use dicts and a while loop for input multiple users. This code keep iterating until user enters 'n' on the second input.

```
print("Welcome to Movie Predictor")

users = dict(Vishnu = 3.5)

a = 'y'
while a == 'y':
    username=input("Enter your user id: ")
    print("Signing in...Please Wait!")

    if username in users:
        print("do something if user exits")
    else:
        val = float(input(f"Enter value for {username}: "))
        users[username] = val

    print(users)

    avg_rating = sum(users.values()) / len(users)
    print(f"average rating: {avg_rating}")

    a = ''
    while a not in ['y','n']:
        a = input("continue? (y/n)")
    if a == 'n':
        break
    else: 
        continue
```